# android listview onitemclick in viewpager

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, onitemclick

I have a problem with onitemclick listener in my listview.
My app has viewpager. On one (first - index 0) of my pages I have listview. When I click button (search), listview is filled with bluetooth devices. Then I can click on any of them and it works great, onitemclick fires and my viewpager changes view from 1 page to 3 pages, and app automaticly goes to second page (index 1). When I slide back to first page (0), I can still click on my bluetooth devices (ArrayAdapter, view in xml). It works always until I slide to my third page (index 2). When I go back from it to my first page, listeners stop working. Where could be the problem? If code needed witch one would You like me to upload?

this is adapter code

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null){
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.bt_dev_list_item, null);
    }
    btListClass btlc = items.get(position);

    if (btlc != null){
        ((ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivLed)).setImageResource(btlc.isOn ? R.drawable.led_green : R.drawable.led_yellow);
        ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvName)).setText(btlc.btD.getName());
    }
    return v;
}
```

This is listview item xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llLI"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bt_dev_back_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivLed"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/led_red" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Nazwa"
        android:textColor="#ccc"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is xml code of my first page

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:background="@drawable/pager_bar_downb" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_bottom_button"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search_button_selector"
        android:drawablePadding="20dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:text="Szukaj"
        android:textColor="@drawable/search_button_text"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvBtDevs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >

</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: upload code ur question is more like a riddle

Comment: just uploaded some code

Comment: Something that comes on top of my mind, do you unregister the listener on the OnStop of the PagerFragment? and maybe then they are not set back? Try mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

Comment: .setOffscreenPageLimit(3); helped. All three pages are on one activity so there is no onStop while switching pages